# Insert target="_blank" into the link.

Tags: php

I would like to insert a target_blank into this button but I don't know how.

I tried inserting it into the href brackets but it came out with errors and my knowledge of php is very low.

Much appreciated if anyone could help me out here. (I would like to insert it in the 'orginal form' part rather than the 'pop up form').

```
<?php
                    $pricing = $subscription->get_pricingarray();

                    if($pricing) {
                        ?>
                        <span class='link'>
                            <?php

                                if(isset($M_options['formtype']) && $M_options['formtype'] == 'new') {
                                    // pop up form
                                    $link = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
                                    $link .= '?action=buynow&amp;subscription=' . (int) $sub->id;
                                    $class = 'popover';
                                } else {
                                    // original form
                                    $link = '?action=registeruser&amp;subscription=' . (int) $sub->id;


                                    $class = '';
                                }

                                if(empty($linktext)) {
                                    $linktext = apply_filters('membership_subscription_signup_text', __('Complete Registration', 'membership'));
                                }

                                $html = "<a href='" . $link . "' class='button " . $class . " " . apply_filters('membership_subscription_button_color', 'blue') . "'>" . $linktext . " </a>";
                                echo $html;
                            ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quotes with a backslash, like so:

```
$html = "<a href='" . $link . "' target=\"_blank\" class='button " . $class . " " . apply_filters('membership_subscription_button_color', 'blue') . "'>" . $linktext . " </a>";
```

Comment: The code is correct, but you can simply use single quotes: `$html = "<a href='" . $link . "' target='_blank' class='button " . $class . " " . apply_filters('membership_subscription_button_color', 'blue') . "'>" . $linktext . " </a>";` as is done for the rest of the quotes in the code there.

Comment: Or even better, use single quotes:

`$html = '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank" class="button ' . $class . ' ' . apply_filters('membership_subscription_button_color', 'blue') . '">' . $linktext . '</a>';`